# How can I calculate correlation dynamically in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table of returns that I want to calculate correlation for every n rows, but I am not sure how to do that. To be more illustrative, my table t is

| sym1 | sym2 | sym3 | sym4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 1 |
| 0 | -1 | 6 | 4 |
| -3 | 10 | 8 | 9 |
| -4 | 19 | -1 | 6 |

How can I calculate the correlation between sym1 and sym2/sym3/sym4 for row 1-3, then row 2-4 etc?

Currently I can only specify column then calculate, but I am trying to find a way that I can fix sym1 and iterate through sym2-4. Here's my current code

```
(cor).'flip flip each {(til x)xprev\:y}[3;]each (sym1;sym2) from t
```

Comment: Does this code work for you? Doesn't seem to for me.

Comment: It only works when I am calculating the correlation between column sym1 and sym2, and I need to drop first 2 rows.

Comment: can you provide an example of which values you want to apply `cor` to? for example if you want to find the correlation between sym1 & sym2, is that equivalent to ``(t`sym1)cor t`sym2``, IE `3 0 -3 -4 cor 4 -1 10 19`?

Comment: for sym1 & sym2, the first correlation is (3 0 -3) cor (4 -1 10), then (0 -3 -4) cor (-1 10 19), basically every time I calculate the correlation of 3 rows. The same applies to sym1&sym3, sym1& sym4. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which may work for you.

```
q)update s1s2:(cor).'flip{-3#'reverse{-1_x}\[x;y]}[-1+count i]each(sym1;sym2)from t
sym1 sym2 sym3 sym4 s1s2
------------------------------
3    4    5    1
0    -1   6    4    1
-3   10   8    9    -0.5447048
-4   19   -1   6    -0.9751578
```

This is only one correlation found between columns, namely `sym1` & `sym2`. The first two results can be discarded since they do not have the 3 values required for the correlation.